# ProC compile on 10g and running on 11g

Tags: c, oracle10g, oracle11g, malloc, coredump

I compiled a pro*c source with oracle 10g and run the application where 11g is installed. Application gives core dump. I get the following trace from DBX debugging:

```
(dbx) where
current thread: t@1
  [1] _smalloc(0x30, 0x0, 0x1dad44, 0xffffffff7b56350c, 0x0, 0xffffffff7b74eac0), at 0xffffffff7b563350
  [2] malloc(0x2c, 0x23e0, 0x1dac88, 0xffffffff7b5633d8, 0xffffffff7b73e000, 0x2000), at 0xffffffff7b5633c8
  [3] sqlalc(0xffffffff7e79dc20, 0x8, 0x1003bf920, 0x200, 0x0, 0x541c), at 0xffffffff7c2a23c8
  [4] sqlbrl(0xffffffff7e79dc20, 0x1003c0300, 0x1003c0328, 0x1003c02a0, 0xffffffff7fffeab0, 0x1), at 0xffffffff7c2ab1d4
  [5] sqlhvdsc(0x1003c0290, 0xffffffff7e79dc20, 0x8, 0xffffffff7ffff040, 0x122, 0xffffffff7e79dc20), at 0xffffffff7c2c5194
  [6] sqlshv(0xffffffff7e2fb350, 0x1, 0x1003c0290, 0xffffffff7fffec86, 0xa, 0x0), at 0xffffffff7c2c59cc
  [7] sqlatm(0xffffffff7e79df78, 0x100151022, 0x100354330, 0x1, 0x5, 0x1003813c0), at 0xffffffff7c2c72cc
  [8] sqlnst(0xffffffff7c2b5288, 0x85, 0x100150f18, 0x1, 0x0, 0xffffffff7ffff040), at 0xffffffff7c2b5618
  [9] sqlcmex(0x6, 0x1003813c0, 0x910, 0x1, 0x100150f18, 0x0), at 0xffffffff7c2a61ec
  [10] sqlcxt(0x0, 0x100150ec0, 0xffffffff7ffff040, 0x100152312, 0x4d, 0x0), at 0xffffffff7c2a6c44
=>[11] upd_prog_status(status = 30), line 476 in "CCFILT_x.pc"
  [12] main(argc = 3, argv = 0xffffffff7ffff918), line 3698 in "CCFILT_x.pc"
```

My question is either it is possible that compile source with 10g and run it on 11g?
What about this malloc error. I read some where that you have to give definition of malloc in your code in oracle 11g?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible that an application compiled with Oracle 10G, also run on Oracle 11G. But is vice versa will not work.

The above error indicates that there is some memory leak in application but the trace does not tell you the exact place. The leak have been long away from the trace.